# jsoup parsing one line from html

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I want parse one line from html site, but my code not working

MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://ru.todaysdate365.com/").get();
        Elements divs = doc.select("div#dateShow");
        for (Element div : divs)
            textView.setText(div.text());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I parse div with id "dateShow" from http://ru.todaysdate365.com/

[html capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW9ZW.png)

Comment: doc.getElementById("dateShow")

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry bro Your date is loaded by JavaScript and Jsoup doesn't support js. Use **htmlUnit**.
Your website response .Look there is no date

```
  <div class="jumbotron" style="text-align: center; height: 314px; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px;"> 
 <div> 
  <p style="font-size: 14px; text-decoration: underline;"> Дата сегодня: </p> 
  <div id="dateShow"> 
  </div> 
  <script type="text/javascript">

                $(function() {
                    var tz = jstz.determine();
                    var timezone = tz.name();


                    $("#dateShow").load("/getdate.php?lang=ru&tz="+timezone);
                });

            </script> 
 </div> 
</div>
```